# pass a arraylist of parcelable

Tags: java, android, parcelable, parcel

I want to pass a parcelable array containing 2 objects between activites

```
Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(act, ChoiceLanguage.class);      
        for(Language l:langueControl.getListeLangues())
        {
            System.out.println("Contents" + l.getTuto_p1()); // no problem here , my objects are stored and i can read them
        }
        i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("listeLangues", langueControl.getListeLangues());
        act.startActivity(i);
```

but when i try to read my arraylist in another activity

```
ArrayList<Language> listeLangues= getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("listeLangues");  

                for(Language l:listeLangues)
                {
                    System.out.println("Contents" + l.getTuto_p1());// error here
                }
```

i got the following error : `03-27 16:26:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(12495): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to com.dev.pojo.Language` when it try to read the second object of my list( the first is displayed)

I do not understand why it speaks about boolean because i don' t have any boolean in my object

Thank you very much

Comment: have you tried forcing the print statement to a string type with the toString() method?

Comment: @Bob Dunakey. Thank you for your reply. I tried your solution but i got the same error. I don't know where does the boolean come from

Comment: What is getIntent() returning?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to fix your issue, but Ive used serializables to pass my complex extras. You may way to try that instead of a parcelable.

```
    i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("listeLangues", langueControl.getListeLangues());
```

to

```
    i.putExtra("listeLangues", langueControl.getListeLangues());
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra

Comment: for that `Language` needs to implement `Serializable`. Bad solution.

Comment: @r2DoesInc i already tried your solution but the same error appears again . Thank you very much